# Persistent MP3 player using SharedObject

Tags: flash, actionscript, shared-objects

I'm trying to create a persistent MP3 player using SharedObject. Initially I tried using frames and while it worked, frames suck so I continued looking into it.

I came to find out about Flash's SharedObject. It seems easy enough but I can't nail down the logic correctly. I've attached a sample .fla for anyone interested to look at. I need the song progress to be stored and retrieved when necessary to keep the same song playing whenever links are clicked within the HTML page.

Here's a link to the .FLA - http://www.grantandrew.com/testing/flash/player/MP3player.fla

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty good introduction to using SharedObjects 
http://jaycsantos.com/flash/the-trick-to-using-sharedobject/